# How to block adding new keyboard input sources from login display?

Tags: keyboard, login, login-screen, input-source

[image]I'm interesting is there any way to leave only one input source for login display and block (disable) adding new input sources?

UPD: I want to get only 1 (one, single) language (input source), for example english (ABC) and block a possibility (chance) to choose another one (any other) language (input source). To uncheck checkbox with "Show Input menu in Login window" doesn't help in my case. Does anyone (anybody) know any other method?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please take a short [tour] of our site for a better understanding of the working of the same. As it currently stands, it is a bit unclear as in what is the real problem you're trying to avoid/solve. What have you already thought of? It always helps to give a start. Also, the volunteers on the site answer best when the question is showing  research efforts. Please [edit] to update. (notify me by @ankiiiiiii )

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options

Uncheck "Show Input menu in login window"

[image]

Comment: it doesn't help me...(

Comment: Neither does that comment. It gives no further information on an already vague question.